# How to swipe many images like Photos app?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an application to let the user swipe between many photos from the resources folder like Photos app .. How to accomplish this or from where i can start?
Thanks

**EDIT**

I used `ViewPager` but it's slow and not smooth although i only loaded few images!
Here's the code i used to load image in the `Fragment`

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_page, container, false);
    String index = getArguments().getString(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);

    ImageView callImage = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    int resID = getActivity().getResources().getIdentifier(index, "drawable",  getActivity().getPackageName());

    callImage.setImageResource(resID2);

    return rootView;

}
```

Comment: viewpager is a good way to start if I understand your question correctly

Answer (score 2):

ViewPager is probably what you want. Each individual item (in your example, photos) is typically a Fragment (but can also be a View), and ViewPager will let you swipe to page between them. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Some additional info about the animations available here: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: Thank for the answer, i used ViewPager but it's slow and not smooth although i only loaded few images!

Answer (score 0):

Find the time to look through open source APIs, Google photos has one, but at the moment I can't remember how to call it.

Better to use tried and tested than to waste time building from scratch.